# Bootstrap, Modal with link inside data-content once clicked close the current modal and shows another modal?

Tags: javascript, html, twitter-bootstrap, modal-dialog

I'm currently having a problem. I need to open another modal once i clicked a link inside the current modal. I tried adding the `data-dismiss="modal"` on the hyperlink inside the `data-content` but no luck and I'm stuck. I'm very very new to bootstrap too. I just started last week.

My code goes like this:

```
<a href="" data-target="#modal1" data-toggle="modal">
    <img src="logos/tools.png" class="pop text-center" data-container="body" data-toggle="popover" data-placement="bottom" data-content='<h3>aaa</h3> 
    <a href="#" data-target="#modal2" class="pop" data-toggle="modal" data-dismiss ="modal"> asd </a>' data-original-title="" title="" ">
<h3>xxx</h3>
</a>

<div tabindex="-1" class="modal fade" id="modalscd" role="dialog" aria-hidden="true" aria-labelledby="modalscd">
  <div class="modal-dialog modal-lg">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button class="close" aria-hidden="true" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">×</button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="proddevtools"><h4>Source Code Deployment</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        <p>Content</p>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
    <!-- /.modal-content -->
  </div>
  <!-- /.modal-dialog -->
</div>
<!-- /.modal -->
```

The js script

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $("[data-toggle=popover]").popover({
        html: true
    }) 
</script>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(".pop").popover({
        trigger: "manual",
        html: true,
        animation: false
    })
    .on("mouseenter", function() {
        var _this = this;
        $(this).popover("show");

        $(".popover").on("mouseleave", function() {
            $(_this).popover('hide');
        });
    })
   .on("mouseleave", function() {
        var _this = this;
        setTimeout(function() {
            if (!$(".popover:hover").length) {
                $(_this).popover("hide");
            }
        }, 30);
    }); 
</script>
```

Comment: As of this day. I am still having some problems with my code. What i only want to do is to click the link that inside the first popup model and to show another second modal once the link inside the first popup hovered model.

Answer (score 0):

```js
$('#myModal-1').on('hide.bs.modal', function (event) {
   $('#myModal-2').modal('show');
})
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>


<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">


<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>


<!-- Button trigger modal -->
<button type="button" class="btn btn-primary btn-lg" data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal-1">
  Open modal 1
</button>

<!-- Modal -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-1" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal 1 content, click <a href="#" data-dismiss="modal">Here</a> to close it
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>

<!-- Modal 2 -->
<div class="modal fade" id="myModal-2" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-labelledby="myModalLabel">
  <div class="modal-dialog" role="document">
    <div class="modal-content">
      <div class="modal-header">
        <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">&times;</span></button>
        <h4 class="modal-title" id="myModalLabel">Modal title</h4>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-body">
        Modal 2 content
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Sorry for the late reply. How do i implement the jquery script for multiple href links?